# In jetbrains idea，how to get SerializedLambda in debug mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, jvm

1.Usual,in my program i Define a SerializedLambda  variable name lambda

```java
        Func1<MyTeacher, String> lambda = MyTeacher::getAge;
```

Func1 is `public interface Func1<P, R> extends Serializable`

when i in idea debug i can use he following code get SerializedLambda
[image]

But when i  define a SerializedLambda  variable in Evaluate

like this and  I get a `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4@7382f612` class  [image]

I try to reflection，but it don't have `writeReplace` method,
I use
[image]

```
  Field h = lambda.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("h");
h.setAccessible(true);
h.get(lambda)
```

but i don't,what should i do if i want get SerializedLambda

Comment: Please clarify what result you'd like to see after evaluating expression. If possible prepare and provide a [minimal reproducible project sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to investigate the problem.

Comment: It looks like this Evaluate feature creates interface instances via [`MethodHandleProxies`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleProxies.html) which is a different (though similar) feature than the facility for statically compiled code (`LambdaMetafactory`). This is reasonable as the `SerializedLambda` requires an actual [capturing class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html#getCapturingClass()) which must declare a `$deserializeLambda$(SerializedLambda)` method for restoring.